# how do I connect tableau tables without getting my pc hanged?

Tags: data-visualization, tableau-api, analytics

[Currently trying this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4yw95.png)
I am trying to analyze some COVID-19 data from Kaggle 
`https://www.kaggle.com/kimjihoo/coronavirusdataset`
I'm using tableau and every time I try to connect more than 9 tables out of the total 11 my pc just hangs 
I've checked the system for low memory and low storage. It seems fine, I have 16gb ddr3, 1tb ssd, intel i7-6500u.
Some help will be very appreciated.

Comment: Did you try using tableau data prep? 
I would recommend you to create a single table source rather than multiple joins for increased performance, Hope this helps!

Comment: thats the thing...how do i do make a dashboard if i cant use the whole data? what is data prep sir?

Comment: https://www.kaggle.com/kimjihoo/ds4c-what-is-this-dataset-detailed-description

Comment: Here in the second point "The structure of the dataset" is what you have to build and create a final table. Tableau prep is a tool used to prepare datasets which have complexity, if you're unaware of it you can also use sql to do the same task.

Comment: I'm already using that as a reference, now ive downloaded prep and trying to join using it

Comment: ive uploaded the image of the joining using data-prep can u help me verify it?

Comment: I just used data-prep and it turns out i have over 5Million data on this little hearted machine. and i dont think sampling covid-19 data will work. thanks for your advice @AbhishekBoorugu

Comment: Connect your dashboard to the .tde file and add a data source level filter so that you're machine is not over burdened.

Comment: Work on the filtered data and once you finish working on the dash you can remove filter and create a twbx file to publish it anywhere.